# how to make dynamic table using JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi i am new with jquery and react I have strong skills for HTML javascript and angular so i know how to make a table with response in json.

I have this JSON and i want to make a HTML table with it please can some body help with it

```
[
    {
        "id": "5a6f8f9eafb2b40824cfde8e",
        "prodName": "Dummy Product 1",
        "prodDesc": "The Fresh Dummy Product in The world part 1",
        "prodPrice": 100,
        "prodImage": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff",
        "prodManufacturer": null
    },
    {
        "id": "5a7031b8afb2b40824cfde8f",
        "prodName": "Dummy Product 2",
        "prodDesc": "The Fresh Dummy Product in The world part 2",
        "prodPrice": 150,
        "prodImage": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff",
        "prodManufacturer": null
    },
    {
        "id": "5a7031c5afb2b40824cfde90",
        "prodName": "Dummy Product 3",
        "prodDesc": "The Fresh Dummy Product in The world part 3",
        "prodPrice": 250,
        "prodImage": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff",
        "prodManufacturer": null
    },
    {
        "id": "5a7031d4afb2b40824cfde91",
        "prodName": "Dummy Product 4",
        "prodDesc": "The Fresh Dummy Product in The world part 4",
        "prodPrice": 300,
        "prodImage": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff",
        "prodManufacturer": null
    },
    {
        "id": "5a7031e9afb2b40824cfde92",
        "prodName": "Dummy Product 5",
        "prodDesc": "The Fresh Dummy Product in The world part 5",
        "prodPrice": 330,
        "prodImage": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff",
        "prodManufacturer": null
    },
    {
        "id": "5a7031f9afb2b40824cfde93",
        "prodName": "Dummy Product 6",
        "prodDesc": "The Fresh Dummy Product in The world part 6",
        "prodPrice": 390,
        "prodImage": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff",
        "prodManufacturer": null
    },
    {
        "id": "5a703208afb2b40824cfde94",
        "prodName": "Dummy Product 7",
        "prodDesc": "The Fresh Dummy Product in The world part 7",
        "prodPrice": 400,
        "prodImage": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff",
        "prodManufacturer": null
    },
    {
        "id": "5a7032ebafb2b40824cfde95",
        "prodName": "Dummy Product 8",
        "prodDesc": "The Fresh Dummy Product in The world part 8",
        "prodPrice": 490,
        "prodImage": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff",
        "prodManufacturer": null
    },
    {
        "id": "5a703a52afb2b40824cfde96",
        "prodName": "Orio-biscuits",
        "prodDesc": "The fresh milk biscuits for children",
        "prodPrice": 30,
        "prodImage": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff",
        "prodManufacturer": null
    },
    {
        "id": "5a7048acd5a5e430d8362671",
        "prodName": "Orio-biscuits-2",
        "prodDesc": "The fresh milk biscuits for children",
        "prodPrice": 30,
        "prodImage": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff",
        "prodManufacturer": "Nestle"
    },
    {
        "id": "5a75f0e4d5a5e430585908d6",
        "prodName": "Orio-biscuits-3",
        "prodDesc": "The fresh milk biscuits for children",
        "prodPrice": 30,
        "prodImage": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff",
        "prodManufacturer": "Nestle"
    },
    {
        "id": "5a75fce5d5a5e41f6067ede7",
        "prodName": "Orio-biscuits-3",
        "prodDesc": "The fresh milk biscuits for children",
        "prodPrice": 30,
        "prodImage": null,
        "prodManufacturer": "Nestle"
    },
    {
        "id": "5a7615f2d5a5e42f8463c1c3",
        "prodName": "parle",
        "prodDesc": "The fresh milk biscuits for children",
        "prodPrice": 30,
        "prodImage": null,
        "prodManufacturer": "biscuits"
    },
    {
        "id": "5a76ee9ad5a5e45884569f26",
        "prodName": "parle_chickli",
        "prodDesc": "The fresh milk biscuits for children",
        "prodPrice": 30,
        "prodImage": null,
        "prodManufacturer": "biscuits"
    },
    {
        "id": "5a775728afb2b451708d0254",
        "prodName": "helo",
        "prodDesc": "check me",
        "prodPrice": 19,
        "prodImage": null,
        "prodManufacturer": "test_one1"
    },
    {
        "id": "5a77581cafb2b451708d0255",
        "prodName": "skype",
        "prodDesc": "comm IDE",
        "prodPrice": 180,
        "prodImage": null,
        "prodManufacturer": "microsoft"
    }
]
```

Please can some body help me that how can i form a table in jquery or react

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is not a question. This is a: `"do the job for me"`. What have you tried? Loop over it and create the table...

Comment: jQuery and React are two completely different things, if you are using React, then you do not want the jQuery solution

Comment: caramba@: I am totaly new to this so that's why i dont knw if it is a angular i would have helped you.

Comment: plenty of examples using either library I would have thought, if you google for it. Plus if you already know how to write it in native JS, then for jQuery it's mainly just going to be a case of learning different syntax for creating elements. React may be a slightly different concept.

Answer (score 0):

For such this kind of rendering first thing you need to take into account that how you'll serve the json file is it through the module bundler (Webpack) by using it inside your Component
`import jsonObj from 'path_to_json_file';`
**or** 
you can serve it through this npm package called json-server `npm i -s json-server` Read Documentation [here](https://github.com/typicode/json-server)
You can run json-server by running the following json-server command:
`json-server --watch path_to_your_json_file`

after getting the json by whatever way you need
you need to make a [fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) request which is the "HTTP" library to get data from your services
then write a react render function like the following:

`

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import s from './Carousel.css';
import Thumbnail from '../Thumbnail';

class Carousel extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        titles: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    };

    render() {
        const propsTitles =
        this.props.titles && this.props.titles.titles.length
        ? this.props.titles.titles
        : [];
        if (propsTitles.length < 1) return <div>There are no items here</div>;
        return (
            <div>
                {propsTitles.map(title => (
                    <div className={s.root}>
                        <div className={s.container}>{title.title}</div>
                        <div className={s.container}>{title.year}</div>
                        <div className={s.bannerThumbnail}>
                            <Thumbnail thumbItems={title.thumbnails} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default withStyles(s)(Carousel);
```

`

Also for rendering component you need to look into JSX react templating you can iterate on your object over .map function